# Possibility to show notes on included PDF pages

Tags: graphics, pdf, include

I include pages from an pdf in my document:

```
\includegraphics[page=4, clip, width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{graphics/lorem.pdf}
```

However, if I make notes in the PDF (i.e. used Skim, exported to "PDF with embedded notes") they don't show in the compiled document. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Isn't `\includepdf[pages=4]{graphics/lorem}` accessable through `pdfpages` the standard procedure for your task? Maybe it solves the issue too?

Comment: Yes, it is accessable, but it does not show the notes either.